# The "http://packagist.org/p/provider-3.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request)

Tags: html, css, angular, laravel-5

I am getting an issue of 400 bad request connecting over http, and it seems the package only wants to be installed via http. I tried an override in composer.json as tried by others as workaround to force https - but that doesn't seem to work. I'm not behind a firewall. Mac OS 10.10.3

**Issue :**

```
composer diagnose
Checking composer.json: FAIL
the property name is required
the property description is required
No license specified, it is recommended to do so. For closed-source software you may use "proprietary" as license.
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request)
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: OK

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]    

The "http://packagist.org/p/provider-2013$c2596c5d04e7701561420666ba120ede9429a69c75b732a5a01b18ebb3d64e53.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request)
```

Composer.json

```
{
"repositories": [
     { "packagist": false }
,

    {
         "type": "composer", 
         "url": "https://packagist.org"
    }
]
}
```

Composer version 1.0-dev (92faf1c7a83a73794fb914a990be435e1df373ca)
 2015-07-14 12:37:15

Answer (score 0):

it looks like iran wifi internet i change to IR-MCI my mobile phone and it is installed as well